# ImportXML parse error - Wikipedia scraping with excel sheet

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape little data into an excel sheet from Wikipedia website using the ImportXML formula.

The XPath code I copied which I got it from the browser.

Here is the Wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago

Scraping the Latitude and longitude which is present on the page.

Screenshot:

[image: xpath error]

This is the code that I get from the browser XPath selector.

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[11]/td/span[1]/span/a/span[1]/span/span[1]
```

Can you help me with the code and help me where I'm doing the wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago", "//span[@class='geo-dms']"), 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey mate, Little help.. Can you help me the code for extracting the anchor link to it too? 

I did tired to change the code to hyperlink class, it returns empty. 

This is the code I tried. 

=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago", "//span[@class='external text']"), 1)


Thanks

Comment: try: `="https:"&QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago", "//a/@href"), "where Col1 contains 'geohack' limit 1")`

Comment: Just tried the script, too much of requests sending from excel sheet for wikipedia scraping is slowing down the process. Can you please help me get a Xpath code of that, So that I can scraping tools like screamingfrog to scrape it faster? Appreciate the help mate :)

Comment: try if this will be faster: 
 `="https:"&QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago", "//a/@href"), 40, 1), "where Col1 contains 'geohack' limit 1")`

Comment: I just tried it on a new sheet, it's slower than previous one. It's still loading even after a wait of 1 minute.